# Split arbitrary column into melted data frame

Tags: r, lapply, tidyr

I have a data.frame with an ugly column with structured data. Each Column can hold from 1 to 40 values of interest. Each value is separated with a html break `"<br />"`. The extracted value as the form of a `1.1`, i.e. an integer a period and another integer.

**How to separate and melt these columns into different rows?**

I know lapply and tidy::separate probably are the ways to go. But I have not succeeded yet. So asking for help.

testdata is here:

```
testdata <- dget("http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=VS2cq2rB")
```

The data frame hold two coloumns: `"id"`, and `"moduler"`.

I'd like to have "id" and "value" instead. The end result should be something like this.

```
"id", "value"
1, 1.1
1, 1.2
1, 1.3
1, 2.4
2, 1.1
2, 1.3
2, 3.3
```

This it my latest take - pretty far from where I started with lapply.

```
origdf <- data.frame()
#names(newdf) <- c("id", 'pnummer', 'moduler')

for (i in 1:nrow(hs)) {
  newdf <- data.frame()
  newdf[i, 'id'] <- hs[i, 'id']
  newdf[i, 'pnummer'] <- hs[i, 'pnummer']
  tmp <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(hs[i,'moduler']), "<br />", fixed=T))
  for (m in 3:length(tmp)+3) {
    newdf[i, m] <- tmp[m]
  }
  origdf <- dplyr::bind_rows(newdf, origdf)
}
```

Comment: @SabDeM what do you see? sabdemtest <- dget("http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=VS2cq2rB") - works for mee (albeit the data looks funny - thats what I am trying to fix :-))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table` approach. Basically I'm just splitting `moduler` by `"<br />"` or `"<br />InstallationsmontÃ¸r"` by `id`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(testdata)[, .(value = unlist(strsplit(as.character(moduler), 
                            "<br />|<br />InstallationsmontÃ¸r"))), by = id]
#        id value
#   1: 2862   1.1
#   2: 2862   1.2
#   3: 2862   1.3
#   4: 2862   1.4
#   5: 2862   1.5
# ---           
# 132: 2877   3.6
# 133: 2877   4.1
# 134: 2877   4.4
# 135: 2877   4.5
# 136: 2877   4.6
```

---

Or similarly with the `splitstackshape` package

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(testdata, splitCols = "moduler", 
       sep = "<br />|<br />InstallationsmontÃ¸r", 
       direction = "long", fixed = FALSE, stripWhite = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use strsplit function with a simple loop:

```
newdata  <-  NULL
a <- 1
b <- 0
for (k in 1:length(testdata$moduler)) {
  M <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(testdata$moduler[k]),"<br />|<br />InstallationsmontÃ¸r"))
  b <- b + length(M)
  newdata$moduler[a:b] <- M
  newdata$id[a:b] <- testdata$id[k]
  a <- b + 1
}
newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata)
```

Comment: Thanks - it worked. Marked Davis answered as accepted, as I think that approach is more robust. But I learned something here also. Great for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `unnest` from `tidyr`.  We extract the numeric part (`[0-9.]+`) using `str_extract_all` from `library(stringr)`.  The output is a `list`.  We set the names of the `list` elements as the 'id' column of 'testdata' and `unnest`

```
 library(tidyr)
 library(stringr) 
 res <- unnest(setNames(lapply(str_extract_all(testdata$moduler, '[0-9.]+'), 
                   as.numeric), testdata$id), id)
 colnames(res)[2] <- 'value'
 head(res)
 #   id  value
 #1 2862 1.1
 #2 2862 1.2
 #3 2862 1.3
 #4 2862 1.4
 #5 2862 1.5
 #6 2862 1.6

 dim(res)
 #[1] 136   2
```

---

Or a `base R` approach would be to extract the numeric elements with `regmatches/gregexpr` in a `list`, get the `length` of the `list` element with `lengths`, replicate the 'id' column from 'testdata' based on that, `unlist` the 'lst' and create a new 'data.frame'.

```
 lst <- lapply(regmatches(testdata$moduler, gregexpr('[0-9.]+',
              testdata$moduler)), as.numeric)
 res2 <- data.frame(id = testdata$id[rep(1:nrow(testdata), lengths(lst))],
                            value= unlist(lst))
```